# how to use include in an html

Tags: php, html

I'm developing a website that has several pages, and to avoid having to write the entire menu I want to use the php include method. However I am not making the menu appear inside the html file. how do I make the menu appear whenever I call include?

```
<header>
        <nav id="navbar">
            <div id="navbar-div">
                <span id="navbar-spam">
                    <h1 id="navbar-logo">
                        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="" srcset="" class="logo1">
                    </h1>
                </span>
                <nav id="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#quem-somos">quem somos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#destaques">destaques</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#representantes">representantes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#clientes">clientes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contato">contato</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </nav>      
    </header>
```

**style.css**

```
    *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'mandina';
    src: url('font/Madina.otf')/*Para navegadores Internet Explorer*/;
    font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {font-family: 'mandina';
    src: url('/font/Madina.ttf') /*Para os demais navegadores*/;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
/* INICIO CABEÇALHO */
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 4.5em;
}
#navbar-logo {
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    width: 17vh;
    height: 9vh;
}
#navbar{
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 4.5rem;
    width: 100rem;
}
#navbar-div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
#navbar-spam {
    position: fixed;
    width: 15em;
    height: 3.5em;
}
#navbar-logo { 
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 40rem;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu {
    z-index: 9;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 1.5rem;
    margin-left: 28rem;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#menu li{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
#menu li a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1.4rem;
}
/* INICIO CORPO DO SITE */ 
main {
    position: relative;
    height: 200em;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
.design-tec {
    font-family: mandina;
    font-size: 15vh;
    margin-left: 30rem;
    margin-top: -20rem;
    color: black;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 6px #f3c569;
}
.linha-home {
    border: 1px dashed black;
    margin-left: 39rem;
    margin-top: -0.9rem;
    width: 16rem;
}
#img-home {
    margin-top: 4rem;
    margin-left: 5rem;
    width: 55vh;
}
.texto-home {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-left: 33rem;
    font-style: italic;
}
#itens-home {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 33rem;
    margin-right: 21rem;
    margin-top: 3rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#ico-catalogo,
#ico-representantes,
#ico-tutoriais {
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
    width: 8vh;
    height: 8vh;
}
#ico-representantes{
    margin-left: 1.7rem;
}
#div-catalogo{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 1rem;
}
#div-representantes {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 11rem;
}
#div-tutorial {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 23rem;
}
#ico-catalogo:hover,
#ico-representantes:hover,
#ico-tutoriais:hover{
    width: 9vh;
    height: 9vh;
    transition: 1s;
}
#home{
    position: relative;
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}
/* INICIO RODAPÉ */
footer {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: blue;
    color: black;
}
```

**This is the index.htm file, which will be the main page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html`
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php require "navbar.php" ?>
     <main>
        <section id="home">
                <img src="images/img-home.gif" id="img-home">
                <h2>
                    <p class="design-tec">Design & Tecnologia</p>
                </h2>
                <hr class="linha-home">
                <div class="texto-home">
                    <p>Modernidade e tecnologia em um produto exclusivo para o seu imóvel!</p>
                </div>
                <div id="itens-home">
                    <div id="div-catalogo">
                        <img src="images/catalogo.svg" id="ico-catalogo">
                        <p id="Pcatalogo">Catálogo</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="div-representantes">
                        <img src="images/aperto-de-mao.svg" id="ico-representantes">
                        <p id="Prepresantantes">Representantes</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="div-tutorial">
                        <img src="images/mail.svg" id="ico-tutoriais">
                        <p id="Pcontato">Tutoriais</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>    
    </main>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just rename your file `index.htm` to `index.php` then at the `index.php`, you can now use a mixture of `php` and `html` code.

To `include` a file inside an `html`, you can do this:

`index.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html`
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
       require "navbar.php"; 
       //or
       // require_once "navbar.php"
    ?>
```

You can read more about using `php` on `html` [here](https://www.ntchosting.com/encyclopedia/scripting-and-programming/php/php-in/).

Note: After changing your extension to `.php`, you can't run the file without a server unlike with static files such as `html` or `htm`.

To do this, you can install a development server on your development environment such as `XAMPP`.

References to `XAMPP` can be found [here](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html).